# Why i can't accept answer right away?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question.

I got a couple answers.

But when i tried to accept one answer i got this:

[image]

What happened? I haven't seen this before.

Comment: @Chris congrats! Is this your first action as moderator? :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Er, on meta possibly :)